# Jacobian of a Variance-Covariance Matrix

Tags: matrix-calculus, covariance, jacobian

I have a non-linear cost function $C$ that is a function of a variance-covariance matrix $\Sigma$: $$ C(w) = \frac{\lambda}{2} w^T \Sigma w + \text{...} $$

I'm trying to minimize the cost over the vector $w$ and for the [minimization](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.minimize.html) it would be useful to have the Jacobian $J$.  What are the partials for this cost function in matrix form?  $$ \frac{\partial C}{\partial w_i} $$

Comment: Assuming $\Sigma$ is symmetric, $\tfrac{\partial C}{\partial w}=\lambda\Sigma w\,\,$

Comment: @greg Yeah $\Sigma$ is symmetric.  I suppose that makes since as an analog to single variable calculus.  If you write up a quick explanation, I'll give you credit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's use a colon to denote the trace/Frobenius product
$$A:B={\rm tr}(A^TB)$$
Write the function in terms of this product and find its differential and gradient $$\eqalign{
C &= \tfrac{\lambda}{2}\Sigma:ww^T \cr
dC
 &= \tfrac{\lambda}{2}\Sigma:(dw\,w^T+w\,dw^T) \cr
 &= \tfrac{\lambda}{2}(\Sigma+\Sigma^T):dw\,w^T \cr
 &= \lambda\Sigma:dw\,w^T \cr
 &= \lambda\Sigma w:dw \cr
\frac{\partial C}{\partial w} &= \lambda\Sigma w \cr
}$$
The properties of the trace give rise to lots of ways to rearrange the terms in a Frobenius product. For example, all of the following are equivalent
$$\eqalign{
A:BC
 &= AC^T:B \cr
 &= B^TA:C \cr
 &= BC:A \cr
 &= A^T:(BC)^T \cr
}$$